# Why does for each loop in java does not access the last element?

Tags: java, foreach, hashset, top-n

I am trying to iterate over an Integer hashset to find the first two greatest elements. My 2nd greatest element is at the end of the hashset and I just discovered that the foreach loop is skipping the last element. Why is this happening?

```
for(int n:set)
{
    if(n>max1)
        max1=n;
    else if(n==max1)
        max2=n;
    else if(n>max2)
        max2=n;
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. 2nd greatest element at the end, and it works. https://ideone.com/MZxzn9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't the loop, but the fact you aren't properly updating both `max1` and `max2` in each iteration:

```java
for(int n : set) {
    if (n > max1) {
        max2 = max1;
        max1 = n;
    } else if (n > max2) {
        max2 = n;
    }
}
```

Note that since it's a set, and the values are unique, there should be no case when `n` is equal to `max1` or `max2`.

Comment: you are right, I am getting used to using hashing based data structures. Started day before yesterday and forgot this property. My max1 and max2 would have been equal and I forgot that this would fail in a hashing based data structure.
Big Thanks.